# script link works in plnkr but not in my project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I was trying to implement full row edit feature using ui-grid. Based on it I found the tutorial and I made plnkr of it.

I included some links in plnkr which is showing me result without any error, but I include that link my project it doesn't work

This script src file is not working in my project

```
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/msrikanth508/uiGridInlineEditPOC/master/Js/vendor/ui-grid.js"></script>

Error which I am getting :-
angular.js:13602 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: InlineEditProvider <- InlineEdit <- GridRow <- Grid <- gridClassFactory
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6-build.4791+sha.5b053b1/$injector/unpr?p0=InlineEditProvider%20%3C-%20InlineEdit%20%3C-%20GridRow%20%3C-%20Grid%20%3C-%20gridClassFactory
    at angular.js:68
    at angular.js:4468
    at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4621)
    at angular.js:4473
    at getService (angular.js:4621)
    at injectionArgs (angular.js:4645)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4670)
    at Object.enforcedReturnValue (angular.js:4514)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4678)
    at Object.origProvider.$get (angular.js:4547)
```

If I dont include above link everything works fine.

here's the plnkr link 
[plnkr link of the working feature](http://plnkr.co/edit/8HdEMVBEt331wNDRqcwb?p=preview)

Comment: Did you check in the chrome network tab to see if the file is requested (disable cache refresh the page).

Comment: yeah. page where I was the functionality of that script tag is giving 304 status code error

Comment: 304 is not modified, so it was using a file from your cache can try dropping a debugger; statement where you define that provider and be sure the script is executing not sure why it wouldn't be if it's loaded though